# How can I change the background color of a Leaflet popup?

Tags: javascript, popup, leaflet

I'm creating a map using Leafletjs, and I'd like to change the background color of a popup (which is currently displaying and image and a link) from white to a different color. It seems that basic background color css syntax won't cut it. Any advice?
Thanks,
-Scott

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After you call leaflet.css, you can include a `<style>` tag with the following rule to change the color of the popup and popup tip.

```css
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper, .leaflet-popup-tip {
  background-color: #000
}
```

Here's a screenshot I took after I edited `background-color` of a popup on Leaflet's homepage.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Open leaflet.css and search for:

```
    .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
    .leaflet-popup-tip {
    background: rgb(111, 51, 51);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

Then change the background value to whatever color you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
      const marker = new L.marker(lastPoint, {
        icon: markerIconSnake
      }).bindPopup(getDataInHtml(dataPopup), {
        className: 'stylePopup'
      })
```

If you want to change the background color of a popup you can use the method .bindPopup (in your marker) and add a css class.

```
    .stylePopup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
    .stylePopup .leaflet-popup-tip {
        background-color: #f4913b;
        padding: 8px;
    }
```

If you wanna know more head to [the docs!](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#popup-bindpopup)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'm using react-leaflet v2 and wasn't able to use css in js with material/core/styles. I created a function

```js
const updatePopupCss = (color) => {
    let popupElement = document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-popup-content-wrapper");
    let htmlPopupElement;
    if (popupElement[0] instanceof HTMLElement) {
        htmlPopupElement = popupElement[0] as HTMLElement;
        htmlPopupElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
        console.log(htmlPopupElement)
    }
}
```

Then called it from the  onOpen attribute like so

```js
 <Popup onOpen={() => {updatePopupCss("#036597")}} >
```