# How can I change the background color of a folium popup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, leaflet, folium

I'm working in folium for map visualization. Do you know how to change the background color for the popup from white to a different color?

From here [How can I change the background color of a Leaflet popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532635/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-leaflet-popup) I know that is possible directly on Leaflet, but I found anything related to Folium!

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Dave, I've been successful in changing the background color of the text part, but not the entire 'bubble' like in the example you linked to.  Would that work?

Comment: Hi Bob, I've been successful in changing that too, by including the IFrame attribute and select a background for the html part, but I have this horrible white border.

Comment: Hi Dave,  Yeah, ok.  Well, best of luck.

Comment: was looking for the same thing. check the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 (manual):

Open your `.html` file with an editor software, and in a `<style>` tag, paste this : `.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {background-color:black; color:white}`

Option 2 (automation):

Create your map and save it in a `path`.
Then use `BeautifulSoup`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
path = 'your/path/map.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(path), "html.parser")
head = soup.head
head.append(soup.new_tag('style', type='text/css'))
head.style.append(' .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {background-color:black; color:white}')
with open(path, "w") as file: file.write(str(soup))
```